# Legend not displaying correctly, when number of displayed lines are reduced

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

- I have an application that will require displaying live graphs over a 48 hour period.
- Using Python, I have been experimenting embedding a MatPlotLib graph in a Tkinter GUI using the Grid method.
- I have got as far as having a live graph with a moving x axis.
- I eventually want to show/hide graphs and legends by selection of checkboxes.
- If you run this example, you will see the problem I am having with the legend.
- With only 1 or 2 graphs displayed, the legend has beneath it the legend for all 3 graphs.

[image: Legend showing 1 line]
[image: Legend showing 2 lines]
[image: Legend showing 3 lines]

```
#Example of a moving graph embedded in a Tkinter GUI using the Grid layout method.
#Every 3 seconds the displayed line(s) and Legend will change.
#This version displays correctly

#On a new Raspberry Pi Bullseye image
#sudo apt full-upgrade
#sudo apt autoremove
#sudo apt clean
#pip3 install matplotlib
#sudo apt install python3-gi-cairo (fixes Couldn't find forign struct converter for 'cairo.Context'

import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
import numpy as np
import time


class Application(tk.Frame): #Class Application inherits from tk.Frame

    #Application variables
    handles = []
    labels = []
    Closing = False
    Count = 0
    fig = object
    ax1 = object
    line1 = object
    line2 = object
    line3 = object
    x = 0
    Y1 = 0
    y2 = 0
    y3 = 0
    
    def ExitClick():
        print('Bye')
        Application.Closing = True
        plt.close()
        exit()
        
    def UpdateTime(window):
        Application.PlotUpdate(window)
        time.sleep(3)
        if (not Application.Closing):
            window.after(1, Application.UpdateTime(window))
        return

    def PlotInit(master):
        print('plot init')
        plt.ion()

        # the figure that will contain the plot
        Application.fig = Figure(figsize = (5.62, 4.04), dpi = 100, layout='constrained') 
        Application.fig.suptitle("Graph embedded in Tkinter Grid")
        
        # graph data
        Application.x = np.empty((0))
        Application.y1 = np.empty((0))
        Application.y2 = np.empty((0))
        Application.y3 = np.empty((0))
        for i in range(101):
            Application.x = np.append(Application.x, i)
            Application.y1 = np.append(Application.y1, i**2)
            Application.y2 = np.append(Application.y2, i*100)
            Application.y3 = np.append(Application.y3, (i**3)/100)
        
        # adding the subplot
        Application.ax1 = Application.fig.subplots()

        # plotting the graph
        Application.line1, = Application.ax1.plot(Application.x, Application.y1, label='100i') #line2, means first item in list of plots
        Application.line2, = Application.ax1.plot(Application.x, Application.y2, label='i^2') #line1, means first item in list of plots
        Application.line3, = Application.ax1.plot(Application.x, Application.y3, label='i^3/100') #line2, means first item in list of plots
        
        Application.ax1.legend(loc = 'upper left')
        Application.handles, Application.labels = Application.ax1.get_legend_handles_labels() #returns i^2 and 100i
        
        # create the canvas within the Matplotlib figure
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(Application.fig, master)

        # create a frame to hold the navigation toolbar
        toolbarFrame = tk.Frame(master)
        # place the toolbar on the canvas
        NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, toolbarFrame)

        # placing the canvas in the Tkinter window
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 0, column = 2, rowspan = 11, sticky = 'W', padx = 25, pady = 5)
        # placing the toolbar in the Tkinter window
        toolbarFrame.grid(row=11,column=2)
        
        Application.fig.canvas.draw()
        Application.fig.canvas.flush_events()
        
    def PlotUpdate(master):
        print('plot update')
        
        #Just as a demonstration toggle the line and legend visibility.
        phase = Application.Count % 3
        Application.Count += 1
        var_handles = [] #initial blank list
        var_labels = []
        if (phase == 0):
            var_handles.append(Application.handles[0])
            var_labels.append(Application.labels[0])
            Application.line1.set_visible(True)
            Application.line2.set_visible(False)
            Application.line3.set_visible(False)
        elif (phase == 1):
            var_handles.append(Application.handles[0])
            var_labels.append(Application.labels[0])
            var_handles.append(Application.handles[1])
            var_labels.append(Application.labels[1])
            Application.line1.set_visible(True)
            Application.line2.set_visible(True)
            Application.line3.set_visible(False)
        elif (phase == 2):
            var_handles.append(Application.handles[0])
            var_labels.append(Application.labels[0])
            var_handles.append(Application.handles[1])
            var_labels.append(Application.labels[1])
            var_handles.append(Application.handles[2])
            var_labels.append(Application.labels[2])
            Application.line1.set_visible(True)
            Application.line2.set_visible(True)
            Application.line3.set_visible(True)
        
        Application.ax1.legend(var_handles, var_labels, loc = 'upper left') #update the legend
        Application.fig.canvas.draw()
        Application.fig.canvas.flush_events()

    def __init__(self, master):
        #create checkboxes and labels within a grid on left side of the window.
        Exit_button = tk.Button(master, command = Application.ExitClick, text = "Exit") #height = 2, width = 10, 
        Exit_button.grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = 'W')
        #start updating the graph once frame.mainloop() is called
        
frame = tk.Tk()
frame.title('Embedded graph')
Application(frame)
frame.geometry('800x480+0+0')
Application.PlotInit(frame)
time.sleep(3)
Application.UpdateTime(frame)
frame.mainloop()
```

- I was expecting the legend to only display 1, 2 or 3 lines.
- I tried only adding the legend in the PlotUpdate routine, it starts well but end up with the same problem.
- I also tried fig.legend().remove(), but this did not seem to do anything.

Comment: Please read how to write a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will be much easier to troubleshoot if you distill this code down into a small working example the produces the same issues as your actual problem.

Comment: While simplifying the code to a minimum reproducible example I solved the problem. I had a mixture of fig.legend() and ax1.legend() and when they are located upper right they overlay. Simplified working code is attached.

Comment: That's part of why it's important to make a simplified example; it helps you see what's wrong. In any case, if there is something for future people to learn from your problem then post your own solution, otherwise you can delete your question rather than leaving it open.